# How to join two table without getting duplicate from right table in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

Tables Details:

```
CREATE TABLE Test2 (
  ID INT,
  Value INT,
  other INT);
  
CREATE TABLE Test1 (
  ID INT,
  TYPE INT,
  other INT);
  
INSERT INTO Test2 VALUES (123456, 5, 12);


INSERT INTO Test1 VALUES (123456, 00, 2);
INSERT INTO Test1 VALUES (123456, 01, 6);
INSERT INTO Test1 VALUES (123456, 02, 4);

INSERT INTO Test1 VALUES (987654, 00, 7);
INSERT INTO Test1 VALUES (987654, 01, 8);

INSERT INTO Test1 VALUES (456789, 00, 6);
INSERT INTO Test1 VALUES (456789, 01, 16);
```

**This is the Query i m using to avoid duplicate from table Test**

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID, t1.TYPE, t1.other, t2.value  
FROM Test1 t1 INNER JOIN Test2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.TYPE, t1.other, t2.value
ORDER BY t1.ID ASC;
```

**Query Result:**

```
ID  TYPE    other   value
123456  0   2   5
123456  1   6   5
123456  2   4   5
```

**Description:**

Expected Result is , when i m fetching match records from tables. Should get all the records from left table(Test1) and avoid duplicate record from right table (Test2).

**Expected Query Result are**,

```
ID  TYPE    other   value
123456  0   2   5
123456  1   6   
123456  2   4
```

**SQL Fiddle Link**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8953fc/29

**Criteria**
When there is ID match should get all matched records from left table (Test1) and from right table (Test2) should get distinct records.

Comment: I removed the extraneous Microsoft SQL Server and MySQL tags from your question. Please don't specify tags unrelated to your question.

Comment: edit the question - pick ONE sql only. Which database version do you want to use? Include the link to the fiddle. What is the expected the results for your query? When there is a duplicate what is the criteria for for the row you want selected?

Comment: @Danblack  ... Thanks for your response... I have updated query..

Comment: You have 1 row in test2 that matches 3 rows in test1. If all rows from test1 should be included in result,  what is the expected output of your query?

Comment: Also, you have both DISTINCT and GROUP BY in your query, that is redundant because in this context they do the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing it on client side (sqlplus):

```
SQL> SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID, t1.TYPE, t1.other, t2.value FROM Test1 t1 INNER JOIN Test2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.TYPE, t1.other, t2.value ORDER BY t1.ID ASC;

        ID       TYPE      OTHER      VALUE
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
    123456          0          2          5
    123456          1          6          5
    123456          2          4          5

SQL> break on value
SQL> SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID, t1.TYPE, t1.other, t2.value FROM Test1 t1 INNER JOIN Test2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.TYPE, t1.other, t2.value ORDER BY t1.ID ASC;

        ID       TYPE      OTHER      VALUE
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
    123456          0          2          5
    123456          1          6
    123456          2          4
```

In SQL:

```
SQL> clear breaks
breaks cleared
SQL> SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID, t1.TYPE, t1.other, t2.value FROM Test1 t1 INNER JOIN Test2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.TYPE, t1.other, t2.value ORDER BY t1.ID ASC;

        ID       TYPE      OTHER      VALUE
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
    123456          0          2          5
    123456          1          6          5
    123456          2          4          5

SQL> SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID, t1.TYPE, t1.other, case when row_number() over (partition by t1.id order by t1.id) = 1 then t2.value end value FROM Test1 t1 INNER JOIN Test2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.TYPE, t1.other, t2.value ORDER BY t1.ID ASC;

        ID       TYPE      OTHER      VALUE
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
    123456          0          2          5
    123456          1          6
    123456          2          4
```